# How can Django get session data in next request?

Tags: django, session, request, response

```
def home(request):
    # logged in
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        request.session['username'] = str(request.user)
        request.session.set_expiry(0)

    # anonymous
    else:
        # how could Django get session data here ?
        cur = request.session.get('username', None)
        if cur:
            pass
        else:
            anon = random.choice(settings.SESSION_NAMES)
            request.session['username'] = anon
            request.session.set_expiry(42)

    res = render(request, 'ex/home.html', {'username': request.session['username']})
    return res
```

I'm trying to understand  about session. In anonymous case above, I set session data 'username' to request that is already obtained. And in next request (after refreshing), I can get session data.

But I don't understand how could it work. It's a new request, and I set 'username' in prev request, not response.

How could I get 'username' from next request object despite not setting it to previous response object?

Comment: The session data is stored in the database of the webserver. Normally a web browser will each time make a request with the `sessionid` in the request, and that thus links to the session data stored in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How could I get 'username' from next request object despite not setting it to previous response object?

The session data is *not* stored by the client, but by the server. Data that is stored at the client side are the cookies.

Django sets a cookie in the browser that by default is named `sessionid` (you can change this by altering the [**`SESSION_COOKIE_NAME`** setting <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#session-cookie-name), and this thus contains an identifier to the session data stored for this session.

The browser will thus each time make a request with the `sessionid`, and if you access `request.session`, then it will look what it stored in the database.

You can alter how the server stores the cookies, and what serializer is used. For more information, see the [*How to use sessions* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/sessions/#module-django.contrib.sessions).

Comment: Thank you for answer.  

so it's my understanding:  

1.`request.session` returns `sessionid` at client's cookies.  

2. Using that `sessionid` django access to database.  

3. Get/set session data by that id in DB.  


  
Do I understand it right?

Comment: @mishy: `request.session` does not returns a session id, it is the middleware that will set a cookie. Normally from the moment you start using sessions.